# Terraform - private dns zone in gap

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-dns, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a private dns managed to make my cluster completely private by following the following link 
https://medium.com/google-cloud/completely-private-gke-clusters-with-no-internet-connectivity-945fffae1ccd.

with CLI

```
gcloud dns managed-zones create google-apis \
--description "private zone for Google APIs" \
--dns-name googleapis.com \
--visibility private \
--networks gke-no-internet-network
```

I am able to create the zone whereas I am unable to create the same with terraform(I am getting 403 forbidden error).

```
  resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "google-apis" {
  name        = local.google_apis_zone
  project     = ""
  dns_name    = local.dns_name
  description = "private zone for Google API's"
  visibility = "private"
  private_visibility_config {
    networks {
      network_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/local.project/global/networks/local.network"
    }
  }
}
```

and I am getting below error with terraform.

```
Error: Error creating ManagedZone: googleapi: Error 403: Forbidden, forbidden

  on dns.tf line 11, in resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "google-apis":
  11: resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "google-apis" {
```

I am not sure why this happening. And in providers I am using google and google beta 2.14 version. I have the owner permissions.

Comment: I'm in the same position; I'm using version 2.13 of the Google provider.

Comment: After digging into it a little, my case was simply missing permissions; I needed to add the dns.admin IAM. This caught me unawares since I had previously added it, but a bug elsewhere was removing the permission before my DNS zone was being created.

Comment: I think there was some issue with. closing brace after network. But not sure why I got 403 instead of syntax error. Able to run that now.

Comment: Same here. Error: Error reading DNSManagedZone "projects/pincopallo/managedZones/my-zone": googleapi: Error 403: Forbidden, forbidden. 
Using:

 * provider.google: version = "~> 3.3"

Answer (score 1):

You may need to double check how your application default credential set is set up.

1. cd into your working directory (where you run terraform init)

   ```
   cd <working dir>
   ```
2. To create a (or overwrite an existing) credential set under your config folder in your home directory, run:

   ```
   gcloud auth application-default login
   ```

You should see an output in your terminal of the abs path where the credentials are saved in.

3. To set your google applications credentials environment variable:

   ```
   export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<abs path to credentials set>"
   ```

Make sure your environment variable project_id is set to the one that you want to create or update your resources in.

4. To view your list of gcp projects:

   ```
   gcloud projects list
   ```
5. To set your current project:

   ```
   gcloud config set project <project_id>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Got this same error when I was trying to add a non-existent network to the "private_visibility_config" section.  The message threw me off because usually referencing a incorrect network name would generate a 400 error with the "reference network resource cannot be found" message.

I'll share my solution because I had to use a double dynamic block for more than one network, and that was also a bit tricky:

```
variable "visibility" {
  type    = string
  default = "public"
}
variable "visible_networks" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}
resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "default" {
  visibility  = local.visibility
  dynamic "private_visibility_config" {
  for_each = local.visibility == "private" ? [1] : []
  content {
    dynamic "networks" {
      for_each = var.visible_networks
      content {
        network_url = "${local.network_url_prefix}/${networks.value}"
      }
    }
  }
}
locals {
  visibility = length(var.visible_networks) > 0 ? "private" : lower(coalesce(var.visibility, "public"))
  network_prefix = "projects/${var.project_id}/global/networks"
}
```